# pasting a picture in a specified range with vba

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have this following code. I want to paste this copied Picture to a range which i select in Destinationsheet. However i only know how to set the Location by selecting .top , .left , .width , .height . Is there a way to paste this Picture in a selected range such as G30:J:30 ?

```
 Windows(osman).Activate

   Sheets("Overview").Range("A30:D37").CopyPicture


  Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet
  Set DestinationSheet = Workbooks(anan).Sheets("Eingabefeld")

   DestinationSheet.Paste

  Dim pastedPic As Shape



   Set pastedPic = DestinationSheet.Shapes(1)

   With pastedPic
    .Top = DestinationSheet.Cells(17, 2).Top
    'Rest of positioning  code here

 End With
```

Comment: If you're not trying to resize, you just need: `DestinationSheet.Paste DestinationSheet.Cells(17, 2)`

Comment: i Need to resize it and why is 17,2 true? do they correspond to G30:J30?

Comment: It's the cell reference you had in your code. To resize use @Sobigen's answer below.

Comment: i deleted that " with pastedPic" part and put "with pic" part which @sobigen has written down. Should i use them both ?

Answer (score 1):

this code is very close to what I want,
I want to copy a range, as an image and insert it in a different sheet and size it to the outer boundries of a cell range.
All is well, apart from one ghlitch, when the routine runs the
"Set pastedPic = DestinationSheet.Shapes(1)" it picks up the last selected and the one before that object, ending in sizing the inserted picture and the shape before last...
the way I manage to get some consistant results, was to change (1) to (2) the one before that, which apparently seens to be the copied entity...
go figure...

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it worked for me.  If you have a multicell range object you can get the width and height.  If you don't change the .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse your picture may adjust itself.

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Me.Range("G30:J30")

With pastedPic
    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .Top = r.Top
    .Left = r.Left
    .Width = r.Width
    .Height = r.Height
End With
```

I tried you code this is what I came up with.  For the copy picture line I actually copy a picture of the cells not a particular picture within those cells.  Is that what you expected?

One other change was I used `ThisWorkbook` instead of your workbook index.  Adjust as necessary

```
Sub test()
    Dim pastedPic As Shape
    Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet
    Dim desitinationRange As Range
    Set DestinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Eingabefeld")

    Sheets("Overview").Range("A30:D37").CopyPicture
    DestinationSheet.Paste

    Set pastedPic = DestinationSheet.Shapes(1)
    Set desitinationRange = Me.Range("G30:J30")

    With pastedPic
         .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
         .Top = desitinationRange.Top
         .Left = desitinationRange.Left
         .Width = desitinationRange.Width
         .Height = desitinationRange.Height
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: how do i add this code to mine ? i am a beginner at this thatswhy i dont know where i should put your code.

Comment: You need to put in in your function or sub. Edit your `With` block for `pastedPic` to match mine.  You need to determine how you want to determine the range you want to fit the picture into.  If you copy my first two lines then it'll fit it into G30:J30.  One thing to note is if the code is in a worksheet module or a standalone module.  The `Me.range...` only works in a worksheet module

Comment: yeah so i should put set r=Workbooks(anan).Range("G30:J30") ?

Comment: You might mean `Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(anan).Range("G30:J30")`  assuming `anan` is a string variable with a worksheet name.  Just to fix that issue early.

Comment: i did this but somehow this code takes another part and pastes in the range that i specified which is Range G30:J30. However the Picture is not the one that i wanted. I think i make a mistake when i wrote the code. Could you edit your answer and put your code in to mine ? I would appreciate a lot!

Comment: It works! thanks a lot! i just needed to Change the shape index though because somehow it pasted someotherpicture which was already in that sheet where i paste my data. I have one last question. Normally Excel creates Picture names automatically like "Picture 677" etc. Can i do Operations now after this code to my Picture by coding pastedPic.Select since i assume the Name of it is now "pastedPic" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104555/discussion-between-sobigen-and-yigit-tanverdi).

Answer (score 0):

once copying the chart, can do this way:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1:H14").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveChart.Parent.Width = Range("A1:H14").Width
    ActiveChart.Parent.Height = Range("A1:H14").Height
```